# MinGW msys package not found: General advice how to proceed

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, compilation, mingw

Every now and then I want to compile something from source with mingw (on windows). I open msys, type ./configure, and it says

```
checking for...xxxxxx
```

There I have the first questions:

- Where does mingw check?
- What does it check for? .dll, .a, .o.,... what ever?

Occassionally there is an error like

```
configure: error: Package requirements <ogg >= 1.3> were not met:
No package 'ogg' found.
```

Well then I google and find "you can output the default lookup directories" so okay, I type `gcc -print-search-dirs` and see a list of directories, for example C:/mingw/lib, C:/mingw/lib/gcc, ...

Those folders contain `.a`-files. And guess what, some of them also contain `libogg.a`. So why is it complaining? Perhaps the version number? No, I downloaded the newest source and compiled it, and put the .a file into the directories. Same error. It drives me crazy! Please give some advice what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally and typically, when a `./configure` script checks for a library that the
package you are configuring needs to link against, it checks at least for the presence and usability of the library itself and also
for the header file(s) of the library, without which the compiler cannot use the
library's API. (I say typically, because what any given `./configure` check
actually does is programmed by the package maintainer. It has nothing to do with your compiler).

*Checking for the presence and usability of* `libfoobar` normally does *not* mean that the `./configure` check searches the filesystem for `libfoobar.dll`, `libfoobar.a`, or whatever. It means that the `./configure` check simply attempts to compile and link a specimen program against `libfoobar` using the commands that are appropriate for doing so, when `libfoobar` is installed.

Often too (and increasingly), a `./configure` check for a library `libfoobar` invokes the
[`pkg-config`](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html) tool to attempt to
retrieve the correct compiler and linker flags for use with `libfoobar`. For this attempt to succeed, a `pkg-config` meta-data
file associated with the library package, `foobar.pc`, must be found in a standard
place in the filesystem, e.g. `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`, `/usr/share/pkgconfig`

For the library, plus its headers, plus its `pkg-config` meta-data (if any)
all to be available for `./configure` it is necessary to install the *development* package
of `libfoobar`, as opposed to the basic package. The development package
usually has the same name as the basic package with the addition of a `-dev`
or `-devel` component, e.g. `libfoobar-dev`

If a `./configure` check fails with an error of the form:

```
No package 'foobar' found.
```

it means that the check attempted to retrieve `pkg-config` meta-data for
`foobar` and none was found. That will usually be because the *development*
package `libfoobar-dev` is not installed, even if `libfoobar` is.